# Database migration using code first in mvc 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have created my mvc 4 application using code first and accordingly database and table also generated now i want to delete one column (from backend) of my table. so i just want to know is there any way so that changes can occur in my code automatically according to change in database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

through package manager console using migration technique

```
PM> enable-migrations -EnableAutomaticMigrations
```

in code configuration do the following

```
public Configuration()
{
    AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
    AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;
}
```

now when model changes do the following.

```
PM> update-database
```

Doing it through code

Use DropCreateDatabaseAlways initializer for your database. It will always recreate database during first usage of context in app domain:

```
Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<YourContextName>());
```

Actually if you want to seed your database, then create your own initializer, which will be inherited from DropCreateDatabaseAlways:

```
public class MyInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<YourContextName>
{
     protected override void Seed(MagnateContext context)
     {
         // seed database here
     }
}
```

And set it before first usage of context

```
Database.SetInitializer(new MyInitializer());
```

Comment: but i do not want to change model manually what i want that model or other resources of code should get change automatically when i do change in database through back end. is there any way ? i do not know so want to confirm. (Thanks to reply)

Comment: @user3698892 hmmm no this is not possible even in database first approach you have to refresh/update model when back end database changes.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you are using code first technique then remove column from your model and run migration script(google it) this will remove column from your database. But what you want is reverse which I am not sure could be done or not.

Comment: Even i dont know so trying to confirm anyway thanks for your suggestion.